# Manjaro no irq handler for vector

Tags: kernel, pci, manjaro, irq

When booting and at shutdown my relatively fresh install of Manjaro (uname -r: 5.9.16-1-MANJARO) on my HP Spectre x360 Convertible 13-ac0XX I get a an error message:

```
[  +0,000425] __common_interrupt: 0.108 No irq handler for vector
```

I looked up a few things online, but to me it all seems very device specific and I can't find anything for my device. Then, `pci=nomsi,noaer` would just suppress the message and not fix it, wouldn't it?

That's why I want to ask, do I need to be concerned about this? Can I fix it and if so how?
I'd be glad to dump any specific command outputs if I knew which...

Comment: I am also getting this on the HP Spectre x360 Convertible 15-bl1XX with Ubuntu 22.04 and kernel 5.15.0-27-generic.